# Xcode 4.3 leaving debug after breakpoint

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I am aware of shourtcuts from: [Xcode 4 shortcuts](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf) but when i'm try to step out after breakpoint and i hit F8 there step into some thread. I don't want to do that. After i saw the infos i want i want to return to my app on the simulator or device and don't want to app stops anywhere. There is a way to completly step out of debug after breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping out takes you out of the function you're currently in and moves you to the function that called the function you were in. Stepping out does not resume program execution. Click the Continue button to resume program execution. The Continue button is to the left of the step buttons in Xcode's Debug area.